# How can i use .htaccess to point to a directory different from the one on the url bar

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

am stuck trying to use .htaccess to point to the template directory for users of my site.

the directory where user is directed after login is mysite.com/lu/user1/ whereas the content i want to load is at mysite.com/lu/default/

what i want to achieve is load content from the default template directory so that i can modify the page when necessary and it will reflect on all user accounts pages.

this whole thing is to say: when a user is in mysite.com/lu/user1/ let content from mysite.com/lu/default/ be served to the user without mysite.com/lu/default/ showing on the url bar. and if the user is at mysite.com/lu/user1/settings/ or mysite.com/lu/user1/settings/?rw=yyy&uui=uuu let the served directory be mysite.com/lu/default/settings/ or mysite.com/lu/default/settings/?rw=yyy&uui=uuu

i also do not want the users to have direct access to the template directory e.g mysite.com/lu/default/

this code was posted to me but i dont know htaccess syntax

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index|excluded1|excluded2)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!u/).+)$ u/$1 [L,NC]
```

thanks for ur tym.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this .htaccess inside `/lu/` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /lu/

# block direct access to /lu/default
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /lu/default [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteRule ^([A-Z0-9]{6})/?$ profile.php?cod=$1 [L,QSA] 

# route every user/* to default/*
RewriteRule ^\w+/(.*)$ default/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: thanks for attempting to solve my riddle

how do i match string like this 5D33W5B8, SIUK1PJ5 (8 characters upercase alphanumeric code) on the base of my site : eg mysite.com/5D33W5B8 i attempted this but it did not work 

`RewriteEngine on `
`RewriteRule ^/?((?:[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*))$ profile.php?cod=$1 [L, NC]`

thanks for ur assistance.

Comment: You can use: `RewriteRule ^([A-Z0-9]{6})/?$ profile.php?cod=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: That's great, answer updated. You may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: pls help here, i tried `RewriteRule ^/new?/$ new.php [L,QSA]` hoping to match and point to new.php 
but it did not work. pls how do i do this?

Comment: can also do something like this
`# stop hotlinking <br>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$  <br>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(http|https|ftp)://(www.)?(mysite1|mysite2|mysite3).(com|net|info|org|mobi|biz)/ [NC] <br>
RewriteRule .(gif|jpg|png)$ - [F]`

Comment: You can use `RewriteRule ^new?/$ new.php [L,NC]` but I suggest opening new question for new problems. Adding new problem from comments is not recommended on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to rewrite to the `default` directory. You can try this rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#redirect to the home page if they request direct default directory
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} {A-Z}{3,}\ /lu/default/?([^&\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]

#internally rewrite to the default directory QSA flag will send any query string attached.
RewriteRule ^lu/(?!default)([^/]+)/?(.*?)/?$ /lu/default/$1/$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks for attempting to solve my riddle

how do i match string like this 5D33W5B8, SIUK1PJ5 (8 characters upercase alphanumeric code) on the base of my site : eg mysite.com/5D33W5B8 i attempted this but it did not work 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?((?:[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*))$ profile.php?cod=$1 [L, NC]

thanks for ur assistance.